# Is there a way to keep the websocket open in windows phone 8.1 app running in the background?

Tags: javascript, websocket, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I have read about registering background tasks and either periodically triggering background tasks or using system events to trigger them, what I would like to know now is whether it is possible to keep a websocket open so that a user may remain online when the app is in the background? How much of the allowed resources will it consume? I assume it is doable, do I need to use the control channel background task? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.controlchanneltrigger.aspx I have been looking for some examples but this page says "No code example is currently available or this language may not be supported." for javascript so now feel at a bit of a loose end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control channel background task is not available in Windows Phone 8.1, However it is available in "Big" Windows 8.1